# change a div properties in php side

Tags: javascript, php, css, web

I'm making a simple Php and javascript project where my css design has some overlay design in it. Now I have a button when clicked it displays an overlay div named "myNav" where a div named "req_form" and form are on it where users can fill out inputs and submit them, then my php code will store those data in my database. I just can't figure out how to replace the div and dislpay success on it after successfully submitting the data in my Php code.

[my overlay div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UDxI.png)

```
<?php
include 'includes/autoloader.inc.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.width="100%";
  }
  function closeNav(){
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0";
  }
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/cssticket.css">
</head>

<body>


<button class="button_a" onclick="openNav()">Create Request</button> //OPENS THE OVERLAY DIV

<div id="myNav" class="overlay"> // THIS IS THE OVERLAY DIV
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
<div class="overlay-content">

    <div id="req_form" class="inputs"> // THIS IS THE DIV I WANT TO BE REPLACE BY A MESSAGE SUCCESS
    <div id="error"></div>
    <form id="form" action="includes/enduser.inc.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="userrequester" placeholder="name" >
        <br>
        <label for="reqtype">Request type:</label>
        <select name="priority" required>
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="High">General</option>
            <option value="Low">Urgent</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <label for="itemtype">Item type:</label>
        <input type="radio" name="typeitem" value="Borrowed" required><label>Borrowed</label>
        <input type="radio" name="typeitem" value="Replace" required></input><label>Replace</label>
        <br>
        <label>Summary :</label>
        <br>
        <textarea name="summary" cols="30" rows="10" required ></textarea>
        <br>
        <button type="submit" name="sendrequest" class="button_a">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>

       </body>
    </html>
```

here is my php file :

```
include 'autoloader.inc.php';
$request =  new usercontlr;

if (isset($_POST['sendrequest'])) {

$date = date ('F d, Y');
$enduser =  $_POST['userrequester'];
$priority = $_POST["priority"];
$itemtype = $_POST["typeitem"];
$summary = $_POST["summary"];
$status = "new";


    $request->createticket($enduser, $priority, $itemtype, $status, $summary, $date); // function where my object stores data in my database
```

What i have tried  already is to echo out some javascript that should have change the into a success message after storing the data inside this php file.

```
echo ' <script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementById('req_form').style.display = "none";
var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
var result = document.createTextNode('Success!');
h1.appendChild(result);
document.getElementById('myNav').appendChild(h1);

</script> ' ;
```

but when I check the console I got an error (enduser.inc.php:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at enduser.inc.php:3
(anonymous) @ enduser.inc.php:3)

Here is also my css if it helps:

```
.inputs {
padding: 20px;
display: inline-block
}

.overlay {
height: 100%;
width: 0;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background-color: rgb(11, 156, 49);
background-color: rgba(11, 156, 49, 0.9);
overflow-x: hidden;
transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
font-family: monospace;
font-size: 15px;
background-color: white;
border-radius: 2%;
position: relative;
top: 25%;
width: 50%;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
}

.overlay a {
padding: 8px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 36px;
color: #818181;
display: block;
transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover,
.overlay a:focus {
 color: red;
 }

 .overlay .closebtn {
 color: white;
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
right: 45px;
font-size: 60px;
}

 @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
 .overlay a {
    font-size: 20px
}
.overlay .closebtn {
    font-size: 40px;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
 }
 }
```

Comment: So you want to post a success to the customer once they submit the form and there are no issues? Is that a modal the form is on? Also, I take it that the post is going to another page for processing and you need to place the success message back on the form page correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to create a header() redirect to your original page once you have successfully queried and successfully added your inputs to the DB.

Something like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['sendrequest'])) {

    $date = date ('F d, Y');
    $enduser =  $_POST['userrequester'];
    $priority = $_POST["priority"];
    $itemtype = $_POST["typeitem"];
    $summary = $_POST["summary"];
    $status = "new";


    // Pretty sure this can be wrapped in your if statement, may need to test that.
    // --> $request->createticket($enduser, $priority, $itemtype, $status, $summary, $date); 
    if($request->createticket($enduser, $priority, $itemtype, $status, $summary, $date)){
        $postMSG = "success"; // sending the success message over url as $_GET
        $host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; // SERVER
        $uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\'); // Directory
        $extra = 'ticketformpage.php'; // the page your form is on
        header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra?$postMSG"); // header redirect with url post added
    }
```

Now on the page you wish to display the success message, we check to see if the GET global isset with success `$_GET['success']` if it is then we set the variable and display them and add some css.

```
<?php 
$msg = NULL; // we set to NULL for when the message is not needed
if(isset($_GET['success'])){
  $msg = "Thank you for submitting through our ticket system.";
}else{
  $msg = NULL;
}
```

**NOTE:** I added the success in a `<span>` tag and added *padding* and *border radius*, *limegreen bg* and *darkgreen color* to associate with success. 10px margin-top for form.

```
 <div id="req_form" class="inputs">
    <span class="success"><?=$msg?></span> <!--// add the success variable here-->
    <div id="error"></div>
    <form id="form" action="inputtest.php" method="POST">
```

CSS:

```
form {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.success {
   background-color: limegreen;
   color: darkgreen;
   padding: 10px;
   border-radius: 5px;
}
```

[image]